# Setting Volume for Video Element in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video, webrtc

How do you go about setting the volume of a video element in react? I know Javascript has the vid.volume property, but not sure what the proper convention is for react.

Here's my attempt at the moment:

```
const Video = (props) => {
   const ref = useRef();
   const [volumeSignal, setVolumeSignal] = useState(0);

   useEffect(() => {
    props.peer.on("stream", stream => {
    ref.current.srcObject = stream;
     })
    }, []);

  const handleChange = (e, value ) => {
  console.log("Volume is: " + value)
  setVolumeSignal(value)
   }
  return (
<div>
    <video playsInline autoPlay ref={ref} volume={volumeSignal}/>
    <div style={{width: 300, margin: 30}}>
    <Slider max={1} min={0} step={0.1} onChange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
</div>
);
```

Comment: What's `StyledVideo`?

Comment: I've edited it to <video> tag to make it clearer.

Comment: did you find an answer for this?